# Redirect proxy traffic through another IPv4 address

Tags: linux, iptables, proxy, squid, privoxy

I have a CentOS 6 box running Squid and Privoxy to create a custom proxy setup. The server has several public IPv4 addresses configured on virtual `eth0` interfaces.

### **My Goal:**

I want to send all proxy traffic through a specific IPv4 address that is setup on the server, but is not the default IP.

### **Problem:**

All proxy traffic is being sent through the default IP of the `eth0` interface. I don't want this IP to be used.

## **Setup:**

I am using both Squid and Privoxy in my proxy.

**Squid**

My squid install is configured on an external IPv4 address `http_port x.x.x.x:8080`and is what a client uses to connect to the proxy.

Squid is using `cache_peer` to connect to a local Privoxy server running on the same server.

**Privoxy:**

Privoxy is setup as local only and has a `listen-address` of `[::1]:8118` and `127.0.0.1:8118` (localhost only). Privoxy does further filtering, that Squid otherwise cannot do.

Privoxy does not do any additional forwarding but filters and modifies header information.

### **What I've tried:**

I tried using `tcp_outgoing_address x.x.x.x` in Squid, however this causes a *"Zero Sized Reply"* error when applied in the config. This is because of Privoxy being involved in the chain. If I removed Privoxy from the chain it works. Similarly I used `POSTROUTING` with iptables and got the same error trying to change the source IP.

I would like assistance in finding a working solution to get my proxy traffic routed through a user specified IPv4 address, with Squid and Privoxy connected together. I am open to any setup changes required for this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: I found my proxy chain is the issue. I have added more information and revised my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that Privoxy was the main issue and decided to use SquidGuard instead, by removing Privoxy from the chain I was able to use tcp_outgoing_address as required.